# How to stop a program using a port

Tags: port

I want to use the port 12345 for hosting a server for an application I have, however the port is already in use by another program.

I have already tried:

```
netstat -anb
```

However, none of the programs listed use this port. Doing some research online I found out that Trend Micro Security uses this port. though I used to have this Anti-Virus software installed on my computer, I have long ago switched to Norton, and am still not able to use this port.

I use netgear, and have no problems using other ports.

Any help will be appreciated.

Mona.

Comment: I can remember that I trigged a virus alert on a hole network when I used that port. Better try some other ;-) By the way this is a question for http://superuser.com, because your question is not programming related

Comment: @rekire But i've got 4 programs that use this port, and would really prefer to clear it up right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetGear has been known to have problems with port 12345. Try calling their support.

Belkin and Dlink work fine. So if possible, try changing your router to see if the problem goes away. If yes, then it is a router issue. If not, then contact your ISP since they block 12345 as well.